# ES6 Template Literals - remove \n from the string

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6

I'm changing my multiline variables to `Template Literals` and it's amazing, but then I noticed that the indents I do are converted (minified) into `\n` with the indentation I did on the original code. How can I avoid that?

Ex:

```
var $div = $(`<div class='proj' id='projects'>
                 <div class='bot-nav'>${txt}</div>
           </div>`);
```

It's converted to:

```
var $div = $("<div class='proj' id='projects'>\n                 <div class='bot-nav'>"+txt+"</div>\n           </div>");
```

And I want this:

```
var $div = $("<div class='proj' id='projects'><div class='bot-nav'>"+txt+"</div></div>");
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What difference does it make? The DOM is the same in both cases.

Comment: It makes on the compiled file.js that is bigger without reason.

Comment: @Barmar: Almost, but not quite... text nodes.

Comment: If you don't want to to have new lines then don't use template strings, that's the point of them after all.

Comment: `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '').split('\n').join('')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While using `.replace` (like suggested in other answers) will work, it is not the cool new shiny way of doing it ;)

I think what you are looking for is a literal tag function (aka "Tagged Templates"), introduced in ES2015.

There are a bunch of them here:

https://github.com/declandewet/common-tags

And you would probably want [`oneLine`](https://github.com/declandewet/common-tags#oneline) (or `oneLineTrim`):

```
oneLine`
  foo
  bar
  baz
`
// "foo bar baz"
```

Note: `oneLine`, obviously, uses `replace` internally.

Comment: I'm not sure if i know how to use this. I added to the index.js on first line `import stripIndent from '/node_modules/common-tags/lib/stripIndent';`
but then on console i have `10Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`. What am I missing? I'm using gulp as task runner

Comment: My guess you don't have Babel set up? It's the 3rd requirement for common-tags - http://babeljs.io/

Comment: I have. Inside a gulp task that deals with scripts by this order: babel, stripDebug, uglify, gutil cached, and rename.

Comment: Do you have babel's 2015 preset?

http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/

MDN suggest also other compilers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Yes I have, i have this on gulp task: `.pipe(babel({
            presets: ["es2015-script"],
            compact: false //using uglify
        }))`

Answer (score 6):

```
let literal = `template     literal
               string so many holes`;

literal.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

This will replace one or more spaces with one space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String.prototype.replace()` method to remove all new lines and spaces after them:

```
var $div = $(`<div class='proj' id='projects'>
                 <div class='bot-nav'>${txt}</div>
           </div>`.replace(/\n\s+/g, ''));
```

Comment: He also wants to replace the whitespace after the newlines.

Comment: @SandrinaPereira Sorry. On the Internet no one knows you're a girl.

Answer (score 0):

To remove leading and trailing whitespace you'd use .replace

To remove the newlines, you can split/join

```
var $div = $(`<div class='proj' id='projects'>
             <div class='bot-nav'>${txt}</div>
       </div>`.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '').split('\n').join(''));
```

Or make a function

```
function someFunctionName(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '').split('\n').join('')
}

var $div = $(someFunctionName(`<div class='proj' id='projects'>
             <div class='bot-nav'>${txt}</div>
       </div>`));
```