# How to remove \n and \t from webpack compiled template literal?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, template-literals

I am developing a javascript plugin, which uses es6 template literals to generate a template, I am attaching a piece of code in my plugin.

```
"use strict";
(function () {
window.project = {
    template: {
        generateHtmlTemplate: function(data) {
        var template = `
             <div class="main">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <input type="text" value="${data.val}" />
                </div>
             </div>`;
       return template;
      }
   }
}
```

When i tried to get build via webpack babel transpiles it to es5 so the template literals like the following. This is the **webpack minified babel transpiled version** of the plugin. This minified transpiled file is used by users. This production build minified file contains \n \t, this is what i want to remove.

(Just think like jQuery development version written with es6 and using babel and webpack to transpile and minify it to form jquery.min.js)

```
"use strict";
(function () {
window.project = {
    template: {
        generateHtmlTemplate: function(data) {
        var template = '<div class="main">\n\t\t\t<div class="wrap">\n\t\t\t\t<input type="text" value="${data.val}" />\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>';
       return template;
      }
   }
}
```

It is filled with \n and \t. I have tried some the [solutions in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142512/es6-template-literals-remove-n-from-the-string). But it doesn't work for me. What this common-tags package does is it **injects the code to remove \n and \t along with the plugin code**.

## What I want

Just remove \n and \t from the output file.

## What I tried

1. I have tried [webpack string replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-plugin-replace) plugin to replace \t and \n. But it doesn't worked. It take source code and tried to replace before transpiler works.
2. I got a hack to solve new line problem by adding \ to the end of each line (also code becomes messy). But even though \t is there.
3. If i try to regEx all \n and \t after build and replacing it is not a good method, it is error prone.

## Webpack production build config

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const ReplacePlugin = require('webpack-plugin-replace');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtactPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const BrotliPlugin = require('brotli-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: ['./src/source.js', './src/ufe.css'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/',
        filename: 'source.min.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtactPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // new uglifyJsPlugin(),
        // new ReplacePlugin({
        //     values: {
        //         "\n": '',
        //         "\t": ''
        //     }
        // })
        }),
        // Brotli compression output for files
        new CompressionPlugin({
            filename: '[path].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.svg$/,
            threshold: 1024,
            minRatio: 0.8
        }),
        new BrotliPlugin({
            asset: '[path].br[query]',
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.svg$/,
            threshold: 1024,
            minRatio: 0.8
        })
        // new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        //  template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html')
        // }),
        // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                    ecma: undefined,
                    warnings: false,
                    parse: {},
                    compress: {},
                    mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
                    module: false,
                    output: null,
                    toplevel: false,
                    nameCache: null,
                    ie8: false,
                    keep_classnames: undefined,
                    keep_fnames: false,
                    safari10: false,
                }
            }),
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({})
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.svg']
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: __dirname + '/build',
        inline: false
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Any suggestions to solve this will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question suggests using a tagged template - can you not do that? Yes, the suggestion is to use a package that provides the function for the tagged template but you can make your own function that suits your needs better.

Comment: But it doesn't worked for me. That package injects the its code to remove \n and \t along with the plugin code. That's what that package does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have got solution for what I want exactly.

Create a babel plugin to remove it.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("[\n\t ]+", "g");

function transfrom (quasis) {
  ["raw", "cooked"].forEach(function (type) {
    quasis.forEach(function (element) {
      element.value[type] = element.value[type].replace(pattern, " ");
    });
  });  
}

module.exports = function (babel) {
  var t = babel.types;

  return {
    visitor: {
      TaggedTemplateExpression: function (path) {
        let node = path.node;

        if (t.isIdentifier(node.tag, { name: "nowhitespace" })) {
          transfrom(node.quasi.quasis);
          return path.replaceWith(node.quasi);
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

It's bit old, but still works.

https://github.com/WebEngage/babel-plugin-template-string-transform
https://engineering.webengage.com/2016/07/15/babel/

Comment: I have retracted my close vote. Don't forget you can accept your own answer. You may want to put some of the content of that in your answer in case the link goes stale.

Comment: What *is* the solution, then? Please include the relevant part from the link. If that webpage goes down in the future then this answer becomes worthless.

Comment: can i know how to use it in webpack? im kinda new to webpack and babel. i follow the instruction on github got this error `Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.` i use webpack version 5.75.0

Answer (score 0):

a more general way of removing line breaks from string literals can be achieved by using the `@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals` & by the help of a custom `rule` in `webpack.config.js`

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals
```

```js
{
    test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: [
          ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
        ],
        plugins: [
          "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals",
        ]
      }
    }
},
```

Answer (score -4):

That's not how template literals work: they preserve whitespace. This feature is very much on purpose as it allows you to preserve formatting much like formatted strings in other languages (e.g. heredocs in [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and triple-quoted strings in [python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp)). If you don't want that behavior, then you can just concatenate plain strings as we did in ye old days prior to ES 6:

```
window.project = {
    template: {
        generateHtmlTemplate: function(data) {
        var template = '' +
             '<div class="main">' +
                '<div class="wrap">' +
                    '<input type="text" value="' + data.val + '" />' +
                '</div>' +
             '</div>';
        return template;
      }
   }
}
```

Note that this is harder to read in the source. Whether or not it's worth it to save a handful of bytes in your payload is subjective but FWIW I'd stick with the template string.

### Edit

If you really want to use a template but strip the whitespace just do this instead:

```
function(data) {
    var template = `
        <div class="main">
            <div class="wrap">
                <input type="text" value="${data.val}" />
            </div>
        </div>`.replace(/[\t\n]+/g, ''); // remove all tabs and returns
    return template;
}
```

Comment: It's the output of webpack production build. so it minifies white spaces.

Comment: @CaptainAdmin it has nothing to do with webpack, it's just a different way of representing the exact same whitespace you have in the template literal in your source file. Again, that is how template literals are *supposed to work*. If you want something else, you have to use something else.

Comment: Your edited solution works when I call template function so it will returns with removed \n and \t. But that's not the solution I need. This is a js plugin that is transpiled into es5 compatible form, and in that file \t and \n need to be removed. Thanks for your response

Comment: @CaptainAdmin then you *need* to **not** use a template literal. Use the string concatenation I posted first. I'm voting to close your question as unclear what you're asking since I've now given you two ways to solve and it's not clear why you can't use either of them. Please edit to clarify and I will retract the close vote.

Comment: Thanks for that vote. I elaborated the question bit more.

Comment: @CaptainAdmin that doesn't clarify at all. Those \n's and \t's are the carriage returns and tabs that you, the programmer, put in the template literal in the source file. Webpack is preserving them when converting the template literal to a string, because for the jillionth time **template *literals* are supposed to preserve literal whitespace**. If you don't want that, then you, the programmer, need to not insert them in your source file, or use the regex replace on the original string (rather than the output file). What's missing, and what's needed, is an explanation of *why* you can't ...

Comment: ... (cont) just change the source file in either of the ways I've laid out to prevent the "problem" from occurring. *Why* does this *have* to be handled in the build pipeline? Why do you *have* to use a template literal even though it clearly doesn't do what you want and there's an obvious easy alternative that does? Include the reason for those constraints in the question and I will retract the close vote: I don't really have any interest in closing your question. I'd rather you edit it for clarity and get an answer you can use and some upvotes!

Comment: Understood. I have changed the source with removing spaces(to avoid \t) and added + to concatenate remaining and to avoid \n. Thanks anyway

Comment: please delete this answer, it adds no value