# Uglifying Template Strings Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, graphql, uglifyjs

I'm using `node-fetch` to send over GraphQL requests in a lambda function. The requests are written as template strings; they therefore naturally are formatted and displayed "beautifully" by my IDE.

Just to save bandwidth, is there any way I can use Webpack to "uglify" these strings, for instance to remove the `\n` characters when compiling my Typescript file?

Thank you!

Comment: template strings? You shoudn't work with graphql using strings manipulations - I guess you're not using query variables?

Comment: I am. I’m just being frugal on packages really since I’m only running a single query or so. Would you still go for a full fledged GraphQL client? Wouldn’t that be an overkill?

Comment: OK, I had to ask, too many strange things in the air ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57533584/6124657 ?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you're loading the files in webpack. The [babel plugin](https://github.com/detrohutt/babel-plugin-import-graphql) doesn't have a minify option. Neither does the loader from `graphql-tag`. Other loaders, like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-graphql-loader), do.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm literally using template strings; they're not really recognized as GraphQL per se.

Comment: You could use something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-query-compress).

Comment: Thank you, yes, that's what I'm looking for... but at compile time ;-)