# Template literals/strings with \n and spaces compiled by closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Some pieces of HTML are injected in the DOM by one of our js library compiled by Closure Compiler.

We use template literals/strings to dynamically change the HTML and also to ease maintenance by keeping indented HTML in our js files.

Unfortunately, it means that our minified file contains a lot of useless '\n' and spaces in the strings corresponding to these template literals (no surprise, this is as per ES6)

**Is there a way to not have all the useless \n and spaces in the minified file?**

*Example of source code:*

```
this.root.append(`
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <span>${someText}</span>
    </a>
    <div class="dialog"></div>
  </div>`);
```

*The corresponding compiled code looks like:*

```
...;this.h.append("\n  <div>\n    <a href="#">\n      <span>"+z+"</span>\n    </a>\n    <div class="dialog"></div>\n  </div>");...
```

Comment: [ES6 Template Literals - remove \n from the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142512) and [es6 multiline template strings with no new lines and allow indents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672651)

Comment: @adiga: I haven't found an answer in these 2 links. A 'replace' function associated to each template literals removes useless char at execution time, not in the minified js file

Comment: have you considered using https://github.com/google/closure-templates

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be missing some config which tells complier not to include spaces and new line.

I found the below config which you can try while compiling:

`compilation_level: 'ADVANCED'`

Comment: We use "--compilation_level ADVANCED": it affects the js code obfuscation level but unfortunately not the spaces and new line in template literals.

Comment: the spaces are inside a string, that's why they cannot be removed.... they are actual data, not code in itself